# Using tensorflow's Dataset pipeline, how do I *name* the results of a `map` operation?

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, mapping, tensorflow-datasets

I have the map function below (runnable example), which inputs a `string` and outputs a `string` and an `integer`.

in `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` I named the original input `'filenames'`. But when I return the values from the map function `map_element_counts` I can only return a tuple (returning a dictionary generates an exception).

Is there a way to name the 2 elements returned from my `map_element_counts` function?

```py
import tensorflow as tf

filelist = ['fileA_6', 'fileB_10', 'fileC_7']

def map_element_counts(fname):
  # perform operations outside of tensorflow
  return 'test', 10

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'filenames': filelist})
ds = ds.map(map_func=lambda x: tf.py_func(
  func=map_element_counts, inp=[x['filenames']], Tout=[tf.string, tf.int64]
))
element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(element))
```

Result:

```
(b'test', 10)
```

Desired Result:

```
{'elementA': b'test', 'elementB': 10)
```

---

**Added detail:**

When I do `return {'elementA': 'test', 'elementB': 10}` I get this exception:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Unsupported object type dict
```

Comment: What's the exception when you return a dictionary?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `tf.py_func` inside `ds.map` works.

I created a very simple file as example. Where I just write 10 inside.

dummy_file.txt:

```
10
```

Here for the script:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filelist = ['dummy_file.txt', 'dummy_file.txt', 'dummy_file.txt']


def py_func(input):
    # perform operations outside of tensorflow
    parsed_txt_file = int(input)
    return 'test', parsed_txt_file


def map_element_counts(fname):
    # let tensorflow read the text file
    file_string = tf.read_file(fname['filenames'])
    # then use python function on the extracted string
    a, b = tf.py_func(
                    func=py_func, inp=[file_string], Tout=[tf.string, tf.int64]
                    )
    return {'elementA': a, 'elementB': b, 'file': fname['filenames']}

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'filenames': filelist})
ds = ds.map(map_element_counts)
element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(element))
    print(sess.run(element))
    print(sess.run(element))
```

Output:

```
{'file': b'dummy_file.txt', 'elementA': b'test', 'elementB': 10}
{'file': b'dummy_file.txt', 'elementA': b'test', 'elementB': 10}
{'file': b'dummy_file.txt', 'elementA': b'test', 'elementB': 10}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm posing a final solution to this question for posterity sake. The code below is a copy/paste example that works under the most complex conditions this question addresses (note that the other two answers aren't copy/pastable code samples):

The goal of the code is:

- Take a list of (big) files and split it into chunks (filename/index pairs)
- Process each chunk using a map operation (generators aren't a workable solution here, see: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16343)
- Output multiple samples from a map operation that takes only 1 file/chunk as input.
- Maintain element naming throughout the process

Copy/pastable working sample for Tensorflow 1.5 / Python 3.x

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

files = [b'testA', b'testB', b'testC']

def mymap1(x):
  result_tensors = tf.py_func(func=mymap2, inp=[x], Tout=[tf.string, tf.int64])
  return {'filename': result_tensors[0], 'value': result_tensors[1]}

def mymap2(x):
  return np.array([x, x, x]), np.array([10, 20, 30])

def myflatmap(named_elements):
  return tf.data.Dataset.zip({
    'filename': tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(named_elements['filename']),
    'value': tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(named_elements['value'])
  })

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
ds = ds.map(map_func=mymap1)
ds = ds.flat_map(map_func=myflatmap)

element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for _ in range(9):
    print(sess.run(element))
```

Output:

```
{'filename': b'testA', 'value': 10}
{'filename': b'testA', 'value': 20}
{'filename': b'testA', 'value': 30}
{'filename': b'testB', 'value': 10}
{'filename': b'testB', 'value': 20}
{'filename': b'testB', 'value': 30}
{'filename': b'testC', 'value': 10}
{'filename': b'testC', 'value': 20}
{'filename': b'testC', 'value': 30}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `tf.py_func` in this case, because `map_func` of [`Dataset#map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) works with dictionaries and other structures:

> `map_func`: A function mapping a nested structure of tensors (having shapes and types defined by `self.output_shapes` and `self.output_types`) to another nested structure of tensors.

Here's an example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

filelist = ['fileA_6', 'fileB_10', 'fileC_7']

def map_element_counts(fnames):
  return {'elementA': b'test', 'elementB': 10, 'file': fnames['filenames']}

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'filenames': filelist})
ds = ds.map(map_func=map_element_counts)
element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(element))
  print(sess.run(element))
  print(sess.run(element))
```

Output:

```py
{'elementA': 'test', 'elementB': 10, 'file': 'fileA_6'}
{'elementA': 'test', 'elementB': 10, 'file': 'fileB_10'}
{'elementA': 'test', 'elementB': 10, 'file': 'fileC_7'}
```

Comment: Assuming `map_element_counts` needs to perform functions that aren't possible in tensorflow (such as read from a custom file format), should I then wrap `tf.py_func` with `map_element_counts` so that I can return the dictionary from map_element_counts after `tf.py_func` returns the tensor values as an unnamed tuple? The problem is that fnames comes in as a tensor, but I need to convert it to a string to process.

Comment: Can you apply the function inside the `map`? `fnames['filenames']` is a tensor

Comment: Yes, that works, as rAyyy also correctly points out with the example.